# How to input the results of the split from the list of sensor data (.txt) into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to input the results of the split from the list of sensor data (.txt) into a variable in python 3?

For example :

I have data .txt:

```
0000003623,-0.028333g, 0.005556g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg
0000003624, 0.028704g, 0.004815g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg
```

I need :

```
col_0 = 0000003623, 0000003624
col_1 = -0.028333g, 0.028704g
...
col_5 = col_0*col_1
```

and the result of col_5 insert/append into file .txt, like:

```
0000003623,-0.028333g, 0.005556g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg, col_5
0000003624, 0.028704g, 0.004815g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg, col_5
```

What is code for that?

I tried before with this data. txt value is :

```
0000003623,-0.028333g, 0.005556g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg
0000003624, 0.028704g, 0.004815g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg
0000003625,-0.028704g, 0.004444g, 0.996111g, 22.925926deg
0000003626, 0.029444g, 0.003704g, 0.995741g, 22.978836deg
0000003627,-0.030000g, 0.003889g, 0.996296g, 22.978836deg
```

When i use code:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\{name_computer}\\zzBelajarPys\\CobaSensor3.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    x=line.split(',')
    print(x[0])

file.close()
```

The result of copile is:

```
0000003623
0000003624
0000003625
0000003626
0000003627
```

But when I use code :

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\{name_computer}\\zzBelajarPys\\CobaSensor3.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    x=line.split(',')
    print(x[0],x[1])

file.close()
```

The result of copile is:

```
0000003623 -0.028333g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/{name_computer}/zzBelajarPys/bacatxtp8_2.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(x[0],x[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: please specify your python version - you added both tags for Python2.7 and Python3, while some things may not be compatible between them

Comment: in python 3 sir

Comment: You expect to have 2 entries per line, but probably you have an empty line somewhere, so `split()` returns a list with only one item, thus `x[1]` will raise `IndexError`, there is no index 1. You can enclose the print call in a try/except block and manage the error.

Answer (score 0):

looking at you data.txt content you can observe that is .csv format actually so I will use pandas ( I've been using jupyter notebook with python 3.6 but you can use the code anywhere that has python 3):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=['col_0', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'])
df
```

output:

[image]

```
df.col_0.values.tolist()
# output : [3623, 3624, 3625, 3626, 3627]

df.col_1.values.tolist()
# output : ['-0.028333g', ' 0.028704g', '-0.028704g', ' 0.029444g', '-0.030000g']

# we need to cast to float in order to be able to get col_5
df.col_1 = df.col_1.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('g', '')))
df
```

output:

[image]

```
df['col_5'] = df.col_0 * df.col_1
df
```

output:

[image]

you just have to save the df :

```
df.to_csv('data.txt',  header=False, index=False)
```

if you do not want col_1 to be modified you just save the content of col_1
in a variable (in the beginning) and before to save the final data you can change the col_1 back to his original data